# How to handle sub-command line in shell script?

Tags: shell-script

I am new to Linux and I am doing a Bluetooth Low energy project using the Intel Edison. The Edison has a Yocto 1.6.1 on it. I used Bluz and gatttool to connect my BLE sensor. But I need to type the same command every time I want a connection. So I want to write a shell script and let it run automatically when I boot the board up.

In the terminal window, I input these command:

```
rfkill unblock bluetooth
hciconfig hci0
export PATH=$PATH:~/bluez-5.24/attrib/
gatttool -b D2:AD:9F:B7:BB:60 -I -t random
```

The it jump to [D2:AD:9F:B7:BB:60][LE]> and then I type "connect"

```
[D2:AD:9F:B7:BB:60][LE]> connect
Attempting to connect to D2:AD:9F:B7:BB:60
Connection successful
[D2:AD:9F:B7:BB:60][LE]> char-write-req 0x000e 0100
```

When I write shell script, how can I handle "[D2:AD:9F:B7:BB:60][LE]>" in my script? I can not put "connect" directly. It won't work.

```
#!/bin/sh
rfkill unblock bluetooth
hciconfig hci0
export PATH=$PATH:~/bluez-5.24/attrib/
gatttool -b D2:AD:9F:B7:BB:60 -I -t random
conncet
char-write-req 0x000e 0100
```

Comment: [link on how to use gattool non-interactively](http://www.humbug.in/2014/using-gatttool-manualnon-interactive-mode-read-ble-devices/)

Comment: This helped me with the same problem: http://www.mathieupassenaud.fr/control-your-plugs-with-bluetooth-and-bash-scripts/

Answer (score 1):

The `expect` tool should do what you want.

It comes with `autoexpect` which will produce an expect script by "watching" an interactive session of yours. Run `autoexpect`, then do everything you'd do in your regular shell, and upon quitting the shell you will get file `script.exp` which you can then use as a basis.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide an example?

Comment: @EightBitTony: thanks for the advice, I added a hint to "autoexpect"